# How do i get the full hour instead of the minutes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm tring to extract hour values from a datetime:

I want all the datetimes like '2021-10-27 04:55:00.000' to show the hour data, so: '2021-10-27 04:00:00.000'

What query do i run to get this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add sample data, expected result and what you have tried

Comment: `dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, datetimecol), 0)`

Comment: This requirement is described too unclear. You should provide more sample data and expected outcome, thus allowing to understand your whole idea. Beside further questions, you did as example not explain whether your times will be delivered as 24 hours format or if you have to do further action in order to get different results for 4am or 4pm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use date maths and a "magic" date:

```sql
DATEADD(HOUR,DATEDIFF(HOUR,0,YourColumn),0);
```

This gets the number of hours between the "date" `0` (`1900-01-01`) and your date value, and then adds that many hours to the "date" `0`.

On SQL Server 2022 (currently in preview), however, you have access to [`DATETRUNC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql) and [`DATE_BUCKET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-bucket-transact-sql) that make this much easier:

```sql
DATETRUNC(HOUR,YourColumn),
DATE_BUCKET(HOUR,0,YourColumn)
```

Answer (score 0):

The current time (UK) is 11:06 (am) and:

```
select format(getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH')
```

..returns `2022-08-12 11`

You can add whatever you want on the end of it, e.g.:

```
select format(getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH') + ':00:00'
```

..which gives `2022-08-12 11:00:00`

NB Format is a SQL-Server function. I'm not sure how many other databases have it.

Comment: Also note `FORMAT()` is [awful](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/how-to-format-dates-in-sql-server-hint-dont-use-format) for performance

Comment: @HoneyBadger True. But any date formatting in SQL instead of client GUI code is really bad design, so it's a race to see which will have a worse effect. However, if doing a one-off query I have no problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

For the string representation of a date and time value you can do something like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(FORMAT(dt, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH'),'00:00.000')
```

see [Custom formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types) and [Custom Date and Time Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 0):

use `convert`

```
declare @a datetime='2021-10-27 04:55:00.000'
select convert(varchar(10),@a,120) + ' '+convert(varchar(2), datepart(hour,@a))+':00:00'
```

Comment: This is far too complicated for such simple things (see also Larnu's answer)